# Website on gcp is not getting ssl certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, dns, google-compute-engine

I have domain say xyz.com ( due to security don't want to share my domain ) on GCE and then create a HTTP LB with FE as Http and https pointing to BE as HTTPS. When i am trying to access my domain its getting secure certificate. But when I am trying to access by CName (www.xyz.com ) then its not getting  cert.

I double check that cert is attached to domain and Cname both on fe https lb .

Also double check that zone created on Cloud DNS has A record pointing to FE of LB and cname pointing to my domain.

Answer (score 0):

This would be kind of difficult to debug without the DNS name or External Public IP, but assuming your `www.xyz.com` is pointing as a CNAME to `xyz.com`, I would then see the SSL certificate to see if the domain `www.xyz.com` exist on said certificate (and not just `xyz.com`).

Additionally, if you could share a screenshot of the cert error with us (omitting the DNS name), that would be of help.